# How to prevent shared Spring EhCacheManager shutdown with one of multiple application instances closing?

Tags: spring, ejb, ehcache

Multiple instances of the same enterprise application in a WebSphere container process messages read from a queue simultaneously. The application has a shared EhCacheManager. As the consequence of an Exception in a single application instance, Spring shuts down the shared EhCacheManager as follows:

```
org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean destroy Shutting down EHCache CacheManager
```

Other application instances running fine at the same time are impacted by the shut down cache manager:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The myCache Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
```

How should one avoid Spring shutdown of a shared EhCacheManager when an application instance is destroyed due to failure while other instances are using it? I am happy to use different solutions such as a non shared EhCacheManager but I failed because I don't know how to dynamically assign unique cache names for each application instance.

```
<bean 
        id="ehCacheManager"
        scope="singleton" 
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="shared" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheManagerName" value="myCacheManager" />
</bean>
```

WebShere 6.1, Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE, EHCache ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NonDestroyEhCacheManagerFactoryBean extends org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean 
{
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            /**
            * Don't
            */
        }
}
```